# Generated email goes to spam and strange header Received: from uknown in email

Tags: php, email, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to avoid email header Received: from unknown and email going to spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273582/how-to-avoid-email-header-received-from-unknown-and-email-going-to-spam)

I try to send email from our server using php and Zend_Mail. I use smtp transport. This is confirmation email of subscribing on my site. But for some reason email that I send has strange headers and email goes to spam folder:

```
Message-Id: <50f41c80.67e3440a.2d32.6aabSMTPIN_ADDED_MISSING@mx.google.com>
Received: (qmail 18457 invoked from network); 14 Jan 2013 14:55:59 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO smtp1-1.searchboxindustries.com) (username@searchboxindustries.com@207.162.215.30)
  by searchboxindustries.com with SMTP; 14 Jan 2013 14:55:59 -0000
```

smtp1.searchboxindustries.com should resolve to 207.162.215.30. Why do I have this header then?

What does it mean list header "Recieved: from uknown"? Can it make email go to spam? How to avoid this strange header and make email avoid spam folder? Maybe I have some problems with DNS settings of this domain?

Spf seems ok:

```
Received-SPF: pass
```

Code for setting headers:

```
$mailer->clearFrom();
$mailer->setFrom($params['list_email'], $params['list_from_name']);
$mailer->setReplyTo($params['list_email']);

$mailer->addHeader('Sender', $params['list_email'] . '.emailname.com');                     
$mailer->setReturnPath($params['list_email'] . '.emailname.com');           

$mailer->addTo($params['email_address']);
```

Code to configure transport:

```
$emailConfig = $this->getOption('email');                                   
        $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($emailConfig['server'], $emailConfig);
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
```

Email config from application.ini:

```
email.name  = emailname.com
email.server = emailserver.com
email.username = email@address.com
email.password = password
email.auth = plain
email.port = 999
email.from_address = "address@email.com"
email.from_name = "Mailable";
```

Comment: You have forgotten to add the code here *how* you send your email.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the following line? This seems duplicate to ->setFrom (see http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.introduction.html#zend.mail.introduction.sendmail)

```
$mailer->addHeader('Sender', $params['list_email'] . '.exampledomain.com');
```

Comment: I use Zend Framework 1.11.2.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Could you please explain how to solve my proble?

Comment: If I delete this header, Sender header will not be added. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Besides I use smtp transport not sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given, the domain of the sender in 'from' part is not the domain that is registered from the IP you're connecting from.

It's a typical pattern for spam to be sent from hosts without registered domain name, or impersonating other domain, so such mail will usually be marked as spam.

If you want your post to be delivered to gmail and not marked as spam, send the mail using gmail or other e-mail provider, not your local SMTP. Note that too many mails sent from one accout could made it be marked as spammer. For mass correspondence you'll need probably to register your own domain.

Comment: exampledomain.com from config is your domain?

Comment: No, I simply change my domain for example.domain in post, but I post for real domain. And I use email authentication SPF and it looks like it passes.

Comment: Could you answer the question what's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: I've said, it looks as your IP or domain is suspicious for gmail. But it's hard to say if you don't post your REAL configuration

Comment: IP and domain is ok. I checked them, they're not blacklisted or so.

Comment: Domain if ok , do you know how to solve the issue? I don't understand what you mean that IP or domain is suspicious for gmail. Why did you decide so?

Comment: It's the gmail that generates that header, but it usually means that the mail was received from sender, whose IP couldn't be resolved to domain name, and that sender has presented itself as exampledomain.com

Comment: Received: (qmail 18457 invoked from network); 14 Jan 2013 14:55:59 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO smtp1-1.searchboxindustries.com) (username@searchboxindustries.com@207.162.215.30)
  by searchboxindustries.com with SMTP; 14 Jan 2013 14:55:59 -0000

Comment: smtp1.searchboxindusties resolves to 207.162.215.30, right? What's problem then?

Comment: I edited question to reflect new headers.